# Why is groupBy() a lot faster than distinct() in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

I have seen a lot of performance improvement in my pyspark code when I replaced `distinct()` on a spark data frame with `groupBy()`. But I failed to understand the reason behind it.
The whole intention was to remove the row level duplicates from the dataframe.

I tried Googling the implementation of `groupBy()` and `distinct()` in pyspark, but was unable to find it.

Can somebody explain or point me in the right direction for the explanation?

Answer (score 5):

I've recently focused on the difference between the `GROUP BY` and `DISTINCT` operations in Apache Spark SQL. It happens that...both can sometimes be the same!

To see this, run the following code and check the execution plans:

```
(0 to 10).map(id => (s"id#${id}", s"login${id % 25}"))
   .toDF("id", "login").createTempView("users")

sparkSession.sql("SELECT login FROM users GROUP BY login").explain(true)
sparkSession.sql("SELECT DISTINCT(login) FROM users").explain(true)
```

Surprise, surprise! The plans should look like that:

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(2) HashAggregate(keys=[login#8], functions=[], output=[login#8])
+- Exchange hashpartitioning(login#8, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#33]
   +- *(1) HashAggregate(keys=[login#8], functions=[], output=[login#8])
      +- *(1) LocalTableScan [login#8]
```

Why? Because of the [ReplaceDistinctWithAggregate](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/optimizer/Optimizer.scala#L1775) rule that you should see in action in the logs:

```
=== Applying Rule org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.ReplaceDistinctWithAggregate ===
!Distinct                     Aggregate [login#8], [login#8]
 +- LocalRelation [login#8]   +- LocalRelation [login#8]
           (org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.PlanChangeLogger:65)
```

===========================
Update:

For more complex queries (e.g. with aggregates), it can be a difference.

```
sparkSession.sql("SELECT COUNT(login) FROM users GROUP BY login").explain(true)
sparkSession.sql("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(login)) FROM users").explain(true)
```

The `GROUP BY` version generates a plan with only one shuffle:

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(2) HashAggregate(keys=[login#8], functions=[count(login#8)], output=[count(login)#12L])
+- Exchange hashpartitioning(login#8, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#16]
   +- *(1) HashAggregate(keys=[login#8], functions=[partial_count(login#8)], output=[login#8, count#15L])
      +- *(1) LocalTableScan [login#8]
```

Whereas the version with `DISTINCT` generates 2 shuffles. The first is there to deduplicate the logins and the second to count them:

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(3) HashAggregate(keys=[], functions=[count(distinct login#8)], output=[count(DISTINCT login)#17L])
+- Exchange SinglePartition, ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#48]
   +- *(2) HashAggregate(keys=[], functions=[partial_count(distinct login#8)], output=[count#21L])
      +- *(2) HashAggregate(keys=[login#8], functions=[], output=[login#8])
         +- Exchange hashpartitioning(login#8, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#43]
            +- *(1) HashAggregate(keys=[login#8], functions=[], output=[login#8])
               +- *(1) LocalTableScan [login#8]
```

However, semantically these queries are not the same because the first generates the login groups whereas the second also counts them. And it explains the extra shuffle step.

It could be easier to answer the question with the code before/after the change. @pri, do you have it so that we can analyze the plans executed by PySpark?

Comment: so how to explain the observation then?

Comment: Analyzing Spark UI, maybe there is something else than only distinct vs group by making the difference? Maybe it applies to specific datasets or queries? Maybe it's just an "opinion" coming from Hive (https://stackoverflow.com/a/31876286/9726075)? No idea. I'll share if I find something new.

Answer (score -1):

distinct() implementation check every columns and if two or more lines totally same keep the first line. 
I think this is the main reason, why distinct so slower.

[Check this topic too.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52056606/10228339)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I didn't find any reason which makes groupBy so faster as compared to distinct().

Comment: if you have 100+ columns, the spark job should compare all columns. groupBy works with one (usually) column, distinct() check works with all columns. Just imagine that, you have check all columns, how difficult task is.

Comment: If I want to remove row level duplicates, then I'll be including all the columns in the groupBy as well, so that shouldn't matter.

Comment: If you use groupby() executors will makes the grouping, after send the groups to the master which only do the sum, count, etc by group however distinct() check every columns in executors() and try to drop the duplicates after the executors sends the distinct dataframes to the master, and the master check again the distinct values with the all columns.  I think this is the main reason.